# How does React's Virtual DOM improve performance compared to direct manipulation of the actual DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, virtual-dom

I'm currently learning React and I've come across the concept of the Virtual DOM. I understand that one of the key advantages of React is its use of a Virtual DOM to improve performance, but I'm having trouble understanding exactly how this works.

From what I've read, React creates a representation of the actual DOM in memory, and when state changes in a component, React first updates the Virtual DOM. Then, it compares the updated Virtual DOM with the previous Virtual DOM using a diffing algorithm, and finally updates the actual DOM based on the differences it found.

However, I'm confused about how this process is more efficient than updating the actual DOM directly. It seems like React is doing more work by creating and comparing Virtual DOMs, so I'm not clear on how this leads to performance improvements.

I've tried to find clear explanations online, but I'm still not fully understanding the concept. Could someone please explain how the Virtual DOM improves performance compared to direct manipulation of the actual DOM? I would appreciate if you could provide some examples or analogies to help clarify this concept. Thank you!

Comment: The virtual DOM doesn't improve performance - quite the opposite. It sacrifices performance for an easier development experience. Spend some time trying to create a complex application by manipulating the DOM directly and you will see the problems that it solves. Mainly, it keeps your state variables and the UI synchronized, which can be difficult.

Comment: If you want hard numbers there have been quite a few benchmarks - here is one: https://plainenglish.io/blog/javascript-frameworks-performance-comparison-2020-cd881ac21fce

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that the Virtual DOM introduces some overhead, but I thought that it can also lead to more efficient updates to the actual DOM, which is often the bottleneck in web application performance. Could you please elaborate on the trade-offs involved in using the Virtual DOM? In what scenarios might the overhead of the Virtual DOM outweigh the benefits of more efficient DOM updates?

Comment: There is no "more efficent DOM updates" - in the end every framework is just calling vanilla js functions. You can just call those functions yourself to get better performance. The issue is figuring out what functions to call and when is complex. JS frameworks automate the UI updates for easier development, but you sacrifice performance in doing so. It's like coding in Java instead of Assembly, more high level, easier development but slower execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The Virtual DOM allows React to batch multiple updates together,    reducing the number of actual DOM operations and improving    performance.
2. React's reconciliation algorithm uses the Virtual DOM to    selectively render only the necessary changes, avoiding unnecessary    re-renders and DOM manipulations.
3. The Virtual DOM employs an    efficient diffing algorithm to identify precise changes, reducing    computational costs and improving performance.
4. React batches DOM    updates, minimizing browser reflow and repaint cycles for better    performance.
5. The Virtual DOM optimizes rendering by scheduling    updates at the most appropriate time, reducing visual glitches and    ensuring a responsive UI.
6. React's Virtual DOM is compatible with    server-side rendering, enabling improved performance and better SEO.